# Python Vector Fields

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to make the following code work but I'm getting the error "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''" on the last line.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame
from sympy import symbols, diff, Derivative

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)

F_x = x*y
F_y = x*y

partial_x = np.array(Derivative(F_x, x).doit())
partial_y = np.array(Derivative(F_y, y).doit())

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3, 4, 1), np.arange(-3, 4, 1))

plt.quiver(x, y, partial_x, partial_y)
```

Comment: what is symbols

Comment: Show some values.  And a full traceback.  I had to remind many SO that `sympy` and `numpy` don't mix well.  `lambdify` is the most reliable way of making a `numpy` function from sympy expressions.  Otherwise it is usually better to stick with `sympy` and don't mix the two.

Comment: `partial_x` is a 0d object dtype array, containing the symbol `y`.  How's `quiver` supposed to plot that?  `matplotlib` is works with numbers, not symbols.